# What's the Difference between "Groups" and "SecurityGroups" in .describe_instances() Boto3 AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

So I was using .describe_instances() to pull information about my companies EC2 instances. I noticed that for each instance under "NetworkInterfaces", it included "Groups" and "SecurityGroups". At a glance, they both seem to have the same GroupId and GroupName pairings. Why is this information duplicated? Or is there a reason why the "Groups" and "SecurityGroups" exist separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [response section of the boto3 method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Paginator.DescribeInstances) you'll find the following description:

> Groups (list) --
> [EC2-Classic only] The security groups.

> SecurityGroups (list) -- The security groups for the instance.

so `Groups` is used when referring to groups in the EC2-classic mode (which will soon be deprecated), whereas `SecurityGroups` is used when referring to groups in the more standard VPC configuration.

You can find more information on EC2-Classic [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html).